# FHIR medication

Tags: hl7, hl7-fhir

I have a data model for medications like this:

- Drug name
- Prescription Date
- Preparation
- Dose
- Quantity

for example:
Bendroflumethiazide (Bendrofluazide), 05/12/2015, TABS 2.5MG,1 Tab,56

I had a look at the medication resource but I am unable to map it. Can anyone help me with this mapping?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Firstly I wanted to ask more details but I couldn't comment on your question because of stackverflow reputation system.*

In FHIR, the Medication domain includes a number of related resources, they are;

- MedicationOrder
- MedicationDispense
- MedicationAdministration
- MedicationStatement

@brillox also refenced this but I will point this again [Resource Medication - Content](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/medication.html) This source is like Master File Notification (MFN for HL7 v2)

Please check examples to see drug names. I also gave one example below.
For Medication Administration please check examples and descriptions, you will find all details you need. [Resource MedicationAdministration - Detailed Descriptions](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/medicationadministration-definitions.html)

An example for compounded medication;

```
{
  "resourceType": "Medication",
  "id": "medexample008",
  "text": {
    "fhir_comments": [
      "  this example includes a compounded medication  "
    ],
    "status": "generated",
    "div": "<div>Hydrocortisone 1%, Salicyclic Acid 5% in Glaxal Base</div>"
  },
  "code": {
    "text": "Hydrocortisone 1%, Salicyclic Acid 5% in Glaxal Base"
  },
  "isBrand": false,
  "product": {
    "form": {
      "coding": [
        {
          "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
          "code": "255621006",
          "display": "Cream"
        }
      ]
    },
    "ingredient": [
      {
        "item": {
          "display": "Hydrocortisone Powder"
        },
        "amount": {
          "numerator": {
            "value": 1,
            "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
            "code": "g"
          },
          "denominator": {
            "value": 100,
            "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
            "code": "g"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "item": {
          "display": "Salicyclic Acid"
        },
        "amount": {
          "numerator": {
            "value": 5,
            "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
            "code": "g"
          },
          "denominator": {
            "value": 100,
            "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
            "code": "g"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "item": {
          "display": "Glaxal Base"
        },
        "amount": {
          "numerator": {
            "value": 94,
            "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
            "code": "g"
          },
          "denominator": {
            "value": 100,
            "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
            "code": "g"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Erdogan, I am totally new to FHIR and I did not realised that I could combine more resources together; if this is the case then FHIR is much more flexible than I thought.


Drug name: Bendroflumethiazide (Bendrofluazide) 
Prescription Date: 29/01/2016
Preparation: TABS 2.5MG 
Dose: 1 Tab
Quantity: 56

Answer (score 1):

What is your data representing? I assume medication prescriptions by a physician.
You should look at the Medicationorder ressource:

https://www.hl7.org/fhir/medicationorder.html

There are many examples of doing it on the FHIR Homepage, like this one:
https://www.hl7.org/fhir/medicationorder-example-f001-combivent.xml.html

In the medication order resource you are then link to your actual Medication resource: https://www.hl7.org/fhir/medication.html

If you have medications from different prescribers or different start/end dates, just use one medication order per prescription.

Comment: Thanks for all the links but i see them already and the medication resource does not match with the fields in my medication object; I cannot even see a medication name to map with my drug name